# multiple selection in checkboxGroupInput and plotting in shiny

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

In my shiny app I have a `checkboxGroupInput`

How should I do the plot command in server function, in a way that I plot the `TurbInt_mean` against `MeanWindSpeed_mean` and add lines (curves) to the plot by user selection ?

I have tried to summaries my shiny app as reproduce-able code as follow (you have to first load the sample data that I have provided)

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Select IEC Classes for TI",c("A Plus" = "ap","A" = "a","B" = "b","C"="c")),
  plotOutput("plotmeanTI",width = "100%") )

server <- function(input, output, session){


  output$plotmeanTI <- renderPlot({
  plot(as.matrix(TI_plot[,1]),as.matrix(TI_plot[,2]),t='o',ylim=c(0,1),xaxs="i",
       xlab="Mean Wind Speed", ylab="<TI>")

  if(input$variable=="ap"){lines(as.matrix(TI_plot[,1]),TI_plot$NTM_A_Plus_mean,col=6)}
  if(input$variable=="a"){lines(as.matrix(TI_plot[,1]),TI_plot$NTM_A_mean,col=2)}
  if(input$variable=="b"){lines(as.matrix(TI_plot[,1]),TI_plot$NTM_B_mean,col=3)}
  if(input$variable=="c"){lines(as.matrix(TI_plot[,1]),TI_plot$NTM_C_mean,col=4)}
})

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

If user select 1, one curve should be added, if select more than one, I want to have multiple curves added to my plot.I can do it for single selection like I have explained in my code, but when I have multi selection it does not work.

My data set looks like :

```
dput(TI_plot)
structure(list(MeanWindSpeed_mean = c(0.292023070097604, 1.12011882699226, 
2.0283906614786, 3.00947886508396, 4.01428066037736, 5.01250749719984, 
6.0080377166157, 7.00777409860191, 8.0049941822883, 9.00201938353988, 
9.99646762244478, 10.9883558855227, 11.9798700705476, 12.976996101646, 
13.9653724394786, 14.9495068163593, 15.9628459343795, 16.9708685581934, 
17.9623943661972, 18.992621231979, 19.9643220338983, 20.9834693877551, 
22.0170278637771, 22.9658904109589, 24.0025266903915, 24.9935025380711
), TurbInt_mean = c(3.02705430346051, 0.420402191213343, 0.264195029831388, 
0.215109260166585, 0.18794121258946, 0.16699392997796, 0.148261539245668, 
0.134479958525654, 0.122038442146089, 0.110595865904036, 0.097103704211826, 
0.0836329541372291, 0.0708397249149876, 0.0622491842333237, 0.0591184473929236, 
0.0611678829190056, 0.0652080242510699, 0.0690131441806601, 0.073762588028169, 
0.0756961992136304, 0.0805696610169492, 0.0817446428571429, 0.0830263157894737, 
0.0827277397260274, 0.0749537366548043, 0.0765532994923858), 
    NTM_A_Plus_mean = c(Inf, 1.10260388189292, 0.642329939163608, 
    0.473065816856713, 0.387417559923049, 0.336769624752903, 
    0.303163441845455, 0.27908457313955, 0.261084722917897, 0.247090026094941, 
    0.235918715179959, 0.226796351934008, 0.219190019655214, 
    0.212713243118379, 0.20720881268079, 0.202452008587075, 0.19816685602934, 
    0.19441329542209, 0.191131377464549, 0.188086340606011, 0.185500707351721, 
    0.18304730715887, 0.180790073836667, 0.178898058874634, 0.177002145398197, 
    0.175335040729601), NTM_A_mean = c(Inf, 0.98009233946037, 
    0.570959945923208, 0.420502948317078, 0.344371164376044, 
    0.299350777558136, 0.269478614973738, 0.248075176124045, 
    0.232075309260353, 0.219635578751059, 0.209705524604408, 
    0.201596757274674, 0.194835573026857, 0.189078438327448, 
    0.184185611271814, 0.179957340966289, 0.176148316470525, 
    0.172811818152969, 0.169894557746266, 0.167187858316455, 
    0.164889517645975, 0.162708717474551, 0.160702287854815, 
    0.159020496777452, 0.157335240353953, 0.155853369537423), 
    NTM_B_mean = c(Inf, 0.857580797027824, 0.499589952682807, 
    0.367940079777444, 0.301324768829038, 0.261931930363369, 
    0.23579378810202, 0.217065779108539, 0.203065895602809, 0.192181131407176, 
    0.183492334028857, 0.176397162615339, 0.1704811263985, 0.165443633536517, 
    0.161162409862837, 0.157462673345503, 0.154129776911709, 
    0.151210340883848, 0.148657738027983, 0.146289376026898, 
    0.144278327940228, 0.142370127790232, 0.140614501872963, 
    0.139142934680271, 0.137668335309708, 0.136371698345246), 
    NTM_C_mean = c(Inf, 0.735069254595278, 0.428219959442406, 
    0.315377211237809, 0.258278373282033, 0.224513083168602, 
    0.202108961230303, 0.186056382093034, 0.174056481945265, 
    0.164726684063294, 0.157279143453306, 0.151197567956005, 
    0.146126679770143, 0.141808828745586, 0.13813920845386, 0.134968005724717, 
    0.132111237352894, 0.129608863614727, 0.127420918309699, 
    0.125390893737341, 0.123667138234481, 0.122031538105913, 
    0.120526715891111, 0.119265372583089, 0.118001430265464, 
    0.116890027153068)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -26L), .Names = c("MeanWindSpeed_mean", 
"TurbInt_mean", "NTM_A_Plus_mean", "NTM_A_mean", "NTM_B_mean", 
"NTM_C_mean"))
```

the head of TI_plot is like :

```
head(TI_plot)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  MeanWindSpeed_mean TurbInt_mean NTM_A_Plus_mean NTM_A_mean NTM_B_mean NTM_C_mean
               <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1          0.2920231    3.0270543             Inf        Inf        Inf        Inf
2          1.1201188    0.4204022       1.1026039  0.9800923  0.8575808  0.7350693
3          2.0283907    0.2641950       0.6423299  0.5709599  0.4995900  0.4282200
4          3.0094789    0.2151093       0.4730658  0.4205029  0.3679401  0.3153772
5          4.0142807    0.1879412       0.3874176  0.3443712  0.3013248  0.2582784
6          5.0125075    0.1669939       0.3367696  0.2993508  0.2619319  0.2245131
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `switch`

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Select IEC Classes for TI",c("A Plus" = "ap","A" = "a","B" = "b","C"="c"), 
               selected = c("A Plus" = "ap")),
  plotOutput("plotmeanTI",width = "100%")
       )

server <- function(input, output, session){


  output$plotmeanTI <- renderPlot({
    f1 <- function(nm1){
      switch(nm1,
             ap = lines(TI_plot[[1]],TI_plot$NTM_A_Plus_mean,col=6),
             a = lines(TI_plot[[1]],TI_plot$NTM_A_mean,col=2),
             b = lines(TI_plot[[1]],TI_plot$NTM_B_mean,col=3),
             c = lines(TI_plot[[1]],TI_plot$NTM_C_mean,col=4)

      )

    }

    if(is.null(input$variable)) {
      plot(TI_plot[[1]], TI_plot[[2]],t='o',ylim=c(0,1),xaxs="i",
           xlab="Mean Wind Speed", ylab="<TI>")
    }    else {
    plot(TI_plot[[1]], TI_plot[[2]],t='o',ylim=c(0,1),xaxs="i",
         xlab="Mean Wind Speed", ylab="<TI>")
    f1(input$variable)

    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

-output

[image]

---

Using `ggplot2`

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Select IEC Classes for TI",c("A Plus" = "ap","A" = "a","B" = "b","C"="c"), 
                     selected = c("A Plus" = "ap")),
  plotOutput("plotmeanTI",width = "100%") )

server <- function(input, output, session){


  output$plotmeanTI <- renderPlot({
      keyvaldata <- data.frame(key = c('NTM_A_Plus_mean', 'NTM_A_mean', 'NTM_B_mean', 'NTM_C_mean' ),
                               Var = c('ap', 'a', 'b', 'c'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  


    p1 <- gather(TI_plot, key, val, -MeanWindSpeed_mean, -TurbInt_mean) %>%
                  left_join(., keyvaldata) %>%
                  filter(Var %in% input$variable) %>%
                  ggplot(., aes(MeanWindSpeed_mean, TurbInt_mean, colour = Var)) +
                    geom_line() +
                    geom_line(aes(y =val)) +
                    labs(x = "Mean Wind Speed", y = "<TI>") + 
                    theme_bw() 

    if(is.null(input$variable)) {

       ggplot(TI_plot, aes(MeanWindSpeed_mean, TurbInt_mean)) + 
        geom_line() +
        labs(x = "Mean Wind Speed", y = "<TI>") + 
        theme_bw() 

    }    else {
        p1

    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: What about multi selection ? It does not work if I choose more than one !

Comment: @AliHadjihoseini  Youq question is `If user select 1, one curve should be added, if select 2, 2 curve and so on !`

Comment: I ment if user select 2 option like select A and B, then I have 2 curve added to main plot : curve A and Curve B ! Sorry if I did not explain it in a proper way !

Comment: @AliHadjihoseini  UPdated with ggplot way

Comment: Thank you very much, Just one point : My main plot is `TurbInt_mean` against `MeanWindSpeed_mean` and then those user selection will be added to the plot as soon as they select by user. So far you have provided the difficult part, may you explain how can I modify your code to have the first part as well ?

Comment: @AliHadjihoseini  Updated the plot

Comment: One last question : Do you know why the colour of the `TurbInt_mean` against `MeanWindSpeed_mean` is changing depend on my selections ??

Comment: @AliHadjihoseini  I think you can check the `colour` option in `geom_line`